# How to overwrite flyway .sql migration file within a jar from my project?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I am working on a Java application that is modular.

Some of my flyway `.SQL` migration files are within an installed `.jar`.

How can I **overwrite** one of those `.sql` **migration file from within my project** so mine get executed for the migration instead of the one provided by the `jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can extract all files from the jar that you want to change:

```
jar -xvf filename.jar
```

Be careful: it will generate a lot of files and folders.

Next, you must find the .sql file and, important, **memorize the exactly name**. Modify the SQL and, next, execute:

```
jar uf jar-file input-file(s)
```

With this command, if the file exists, it will overwrite it. You can execute your .jar with your new file!

I use it with maven jars to modify pom.xml properties and it works. I don't know how your .jar save the .sql files.

Comment: I can already add a .sql files in my project at the same resource location. I rather not use a curious command that will edit the jar (i don't want to touch the jar at all) and solve it programmatically.  do you have another option that could help achieve this. Thanks a lot for your answer and comment.

Comment: You can not because the configuration file inside the jar has configured to point this specific .sql files. Better option may be change the configuration files to point external sqls. But, in any case, you can not do it without modify the jar because the jar is configured to use the .sql files inside it. I don't know if the project is public or private, but with more information, I probably understand better your case and your need.